# Declare type for a variable which contains a reference to a generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In essense, instead of writing

```
function test<T>(param: T): T {
  return param;
}

test<string>("xxx");
```

I want to have a type declaration which can be applied to an arrow function value assigned to a variable.

```
type X<T> = (param: T) => T;
const test: X<T> = (param) => param; // <- ????
test<string>("XXX")
```

Is it possible in TS 2.5 in a non-hacky way?
.... or at least in a hacky way?

**Background**: I'm trying to migrate existing ES6 code to Typescript.
The function implementation in ES6 looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as recompose from "recompose"

const formEnhancer = recompose.withContext(
  { form: React.PropTypes.any },
  function getChildContext(props) {
    const { value, errors, onChange } = props;
    return { form: { value, errors, onChange }};
  }
);
```

`value` has `V` type, `errors` has `IErrors<V>` type and `onChange` has `ChangeHandler<V>` type.

The expected type of the function is

```
export type FormEnhancer<V> =
  recompose.InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<{}, Props<V>>;
```

which is a function interface:

```
export interface InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TInjectedProps, TNeedsProps> {
  <P extends TInjectedProps>(component: Component<P>):
    React.ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof TInjectedProps> & TNeedsProps>
}
```

The tricky part is I can't actually find a way to add this type declaration to the variable.

Writing something like

```
const formDecorator: FormEnhancer<V> = ...
```

leads to an immediate failure, as `V` is not defined.

The best version I was able to get was wrapping `recompose.withContext` into my own explicit function

```
function formEnhancer<V>(target: React.ComponentType) {
  return recompose.withContext<IContextProps<V>, Props<V>>(
    { form: React.PropTypes.any },
    function getChildContext(props) {
      const { value, errors, onChange } = props;
      return { form: { value, errors, onChange }};
    }
  )(target);
}
```

which doesn't quite solve the problem as I'm still able to write

```
const raw = ({ foo }) => <input type="text" />;
const Wrapped = formEnhancer(raw);
```

which means that TS was not able to infer the props type for the target.
Being able to write something like

```
function formEnhancer<V>(target: React.ComponentType<P extends Props<V>>) {
```

would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const test = (<T>(param: T) => param);
```

This would pass the definition of `X<T>` which is any function that returns the same type that the first argument.

Comment: I would have thought it would need to return T, not param?   What does that even mean?

Comment: @AmmoGoettsch It is a generic identity function example in typescript. T can't be returned as it is a type.

Comment: I misread what you wrote there as a function type decl because of the return and body braces omitted.  I think all you wrote there was `function test<T>(param: T) { return param; }` which does not solve the problem posed.  See my suggested answer.

Comment: @AmmoGoettsch Please, see that in the first few lines the OP showed that he doesn't know how to write arrow generic functions `const test: X<T> = (param) => param; // <- ????`. Which is what he's asking for. The rest, is labeled as **background context**. You are answering to the background.

Comment: If you are correct in what the question was, then it was a trivial question with a ton of extra detail.  I choose to believe it was the more interesting question, which is how to write a signature for a function that restricts its arguments to be specializations of a specific generic.   That's actually somewhat interesting and so that's what I answered.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
function formEnhancer<V, P extends Props<V>>(target: React.ComponentType<P>): void {
  ...
}
```

or by shorter example:

```
class A<T> {
    a: T;
}
class B<T> {
    b: T;
}
function restricted1<P>(target: A<P>): void {
}

function restricted2<V, P extends B<V>>(target: A<P>): void {
}

let a1: A<number>;
let c: number;
let a2: A<B<number>>;

restricted1(a1); // succeeds
restricted1(c); // fails

restricted2(a1); // fails
restricted2(a2); // succeeds
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but in the first lines of the OP question, you can see him asking: `Is it possible in TS 2.5 in a non-hacky way? .... or at least in a hacky way?`. I've directly answered him. It looks like he doesn't know how to write generics within arrow functions.

Comment: I think the only problem they had is that they have to make their generic have two template parameters, like I showed in my example.  That way, one is the base type and the other can be restricted to extend some other generic specialized for that base type.  That way, they gets what they were looking for.  This was not answered in your answer.